# How to add more space between the text and its underline in Google Doc?

Tags: google-docs

Underline is being added to Links automatically when I work on Google documents. However, it makes texts not easy to read. Is there any way that lets me pull it down a bit?

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have got any solution for this.